# Flex Slider: Adding text overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

https://jsfiddle.net/ekv8w2e4/1/

I have read a few stackoverflow answers to problems people are having with flex slider but none of them seem to work for me. I have 5 slides but I can only get the text to appear on the first slide, it doens't matter where I put the HTML, it always displays on the first slide. I want each slide to have its own set of text. The css that isn't included below is the css that comes with flex slider.

```
    <div class="maxContainerSlider">
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
   <li><img src="ac1.png" alt="AC1" /></li>
   <li><img src="ac2.png" alt="AC2" /></li>
   <li><img src="ac3.png" alt="AC3" />
<span class="flex-caption">
Business professionals seek timely news and information from<br> reliable sources that can be organized, analyzed, and shared<br> efficiently – to uncover opportunity, reduce risk, and foster<br> creativity.</li>
   <li><img src="ac4.png" alt="AC4" /></li>
   <li><img src="ac5.png" alt="AC5" /></li> 
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>


    .flex-caption {
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    top: 80px;
    left: 1540px;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index:10;
}
.maxContainerSlider{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
    height: 400px;}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you provide this code in fiddle? It will easier to use to answer you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me so quickly.

Here it is in fiddle;

https://jsfiddle.net/ekv8w2e4/

Comment: I can see the `caption` only in the third slide and it "slide" with his parent.

Comment: I'm not sure entirely what you mean. I have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ekv8w2e4/1/ because the first picture on the first slide had text on it so it was confusing but I've removed that. I just want to be able to have a different caption of text for each slide, no matter where I put the caption it only ever appears on the first slide. Any idea of how to change it?